# Lookup Field functionality in a SharePoint Tenant

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, site-collection, site

***Problem:***
I have a request that involves a lookup field for a list that currently is housed on the same SharePoint tenant but on a different site collection.

***Question:***
Is it possible to do a lookup across different site collections in SharePoint online if they are on the same tenant? Or does the lookup value have to come from a list on the same site collection
?

Comment: Check if it is possible using content type hub: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/publish-a-content-type-from-a-content-publishing-hub-58081155-118d-4e7a-9cc5-d43b5dbb7d02

Answer (score 0):

No. You cannot do OOTB to get Lookup from other site/site collection.
You can build a custom solution to get that information from other list like Power app or SPFX.

For OOTB , lookup information can be from same site.